# How to create grid border?

Tags: windows-phone-7

[image]

This is what I'm trying to create. White areas are `System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle` in a `Grid`. This is my code for creating grid, columns, rows and rectangles;

```
Grid newGrid = new Grid();

for(int r=0; r<10; r++ ) {
    newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(
        new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
    for( int c=0; c<10; c++ ) {
        newGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(30) });
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle{
            Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(rec, c);
        Grid.SetRow(rec, r);
        newGrid.Children.Add(rec);
    }
}

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(newGrid);
```

But I have not any idea how can add borders as we can see in picture. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You might consider using a TileBrush (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.tilebrush.aspx)

Comment: @miqbal What happened to your code? Doesn't it work or what?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SolidColorBrush blackBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    blackBrush.Color = Colors.Black;

rec.Stroke = blackBrush;
```

Comment: But in this case, as if grid border is less thickness than cells borders.